# Validacion en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas Noches, tengo el siguiente ejercicio en el que pido una respuesta y existen dos opciones (S/N), S o N (si o no), el programa va de maravilla sin embargo la validación de que solo sea S o N, no logro hacerla funcionar. Si pongo alguna otra letra que no sea S o N el programa sigue corriendo. Mi duda es como y donde hago al validación...

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "iomanip"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int i, n, cn = 0, combo, c1, c2, c3;
int c1total = 0, c2total = 0, c3total = 0;
float combo1 = 8500, combo2 = 11700, combo3 = 15000;
float descuento = 0, tdescuento= 0, subtotal, total, ttotal = 0, total_neto;
char nombre[30], carnet = 's';

cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
cout<<"\n\nCantidad de Personas para Atender: ";
cin>>n;

for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    cn++;
    //system("cls");
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
    cout<<"\n\n< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nNombre del Ciudadano: "<<cn;cout<<" ";
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"\nPosee Carnet de la Patria (S/N): ";
    cin>>carnet;

    if(carnet == 's' || carnet =='S')
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
        cout<<"\n\nCombos Disponibles: ";
        cout<<"\n\nCombo 1 (Bs. 8500)";
        cout<<"\nCombo 2 (Bs. 11700)";
        cout<<"\nCombo 3 (Bs. 15000)";
        cout<<"\n\nCombo a Comprar: ";
        cin>>combo;

        switch (combo)
        {
            case 1:

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo 1 (Bs. 8500)";
            cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
            cin>>c1;

            subtotal = c1 * combo1;
            if(subtotal > 50000)
                descuento = subtotal * 8.7/100;
            total = subtotal - descuento;
            tdescuento = tdescuento + descuento;
            c1total = c1total + c1;
            ttotal = ttotal + total;

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\n< - F A C T U R A - >";
            cout<<"\n\nCliente: "<<nombre;
            cout<<"\n\nSubtotal: Bs. "<<subtotal;
            cout<<"\nDescuento: Bs. -"<<descuento;
            cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total;
            break;

        case 2:

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo 2 (Bs. 11700)";
            cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
            cin>>c2;

            subtotal = c2 * combo2;
            if(subtotal > 50000)
                descuento = subtotal * 8.7/100;
            total = subtotal - descuento;
            tdescuento = tdescuento + descuento;
            c2total = c2total + c2;
            ttotal = ttotal + total;

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\n< - F A C T U R A - >";
            cout<<"\n\nCliente: "<<nombre;
            cout<<"\n\nSubtotal: Bs. "<<subtotal;
            cout<<"\nDescuento: Bs. -"<<descuento;
            cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total;
            break;

        case 3:

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo 3 (Bs. 15000)";
            cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
            cin>>c3;

            subtotal = c3 * combo3;
            if(subtotal > 50000)
                descuento = subtotal * 8.7/100;
            total = subtotal - descuento;
            tdescuento = tdescuento + descuento;
            c3total = c3total + c3;
            ttotal = ttotal + total;

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\n< - F A C T U R A - >";
            cout<<"\n\nCliente: "<<nombre;
            cout<<"\n\nSubtotal: Bs. "<<subtotal;
            cout<<"\nDescuento: Bs. -"<<descuento;
            cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total;
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Opcion Invalida, Intente Nuevamente";
            cn--;
        }
        subtotal = 0;
        descuento = 0;
        total = 0;

    }else

       if(carnet == 'n' || carnet == 'N')
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo 3 (Bs. 15000)";
            cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
            cin>>c3;
            if(c3 >= 2)
                {
                    cout<<"\nSolo puede Comprar Uno";
                    cout<<"\nLe Invitamos a Sacarse el Carnet de la Patria";
                    cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
                    cin>>c3;
                }

            total = c3 * combo3;
            c3total = c3total + c3;
            ttotal = ttotal + total;

            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\n< - F A C T U R A - >";
            cout<<"\n\nCliente: "<<nombre;
            cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total;
        }

}

system("cls");
cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
cout<<"\n\nCantidad de Combo 1 Vendido: "<<c1total;
cout<<"\nCantidad de Combo 2 Vendido: "<<c2total;
cout<<"\nCantidad de Combo 3 Vendido: "<<c3total;
cout<<"\n\nTotal General Facturado: Bs. "<<ttotal;
cout<<"\n\nTotal Descontado: Bs. "<<tdescuento;
total_neto = ttotal - tdescuento;
cout<<"\n\nTotal en Ganancias: Bs. "<<total_neto;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminando código intermedio la parte que importa luce así:

```
cout<<"\nPosee Carnet de la Patria (S/N): ";
cin>>carnet;

if(carnet == 's' || carnet =='S')
{
  // ...
}else if(carnet == 'n' || carnet == 'N')
{
  // ...
}
```

Si quieres mostrar un mensaje de erro deberías añadir un último `else` a esa secuncia. Además, lo lógico sería que ante una entrada incorrecta el programa volviese a preguntar... para eso necesitas un bucle. Un ejemplo:

```
bool opcionCorrecta = true;
while( opcionCorrecta )
{
  cout<<"\nPosee Carnet de la Patria (S/N): ";
  cin>>carnet;

  if(carnet == 's' || carnet =='S')
  {
    // ...
    opcionCorrecta = true;
  }else if(carnet == 'n' || carnet == 'N')
  {
    // ...
    opcionCorrecta = true;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "ERROR. Elige una opción válida"; // Por ejemplo
    opcionCorrecta = false;
  }
}
```

Considera también dividir el programa en funciones más cortas y sencillas para mejorar su legibilidad.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ha funcionado, poco a poco voy aprendiendo. Sin embargo quedo un problema, pareciera que el for no funcionara... Si le digo que solo atienda a 2 personas, se sigue repitiendo el ciclo sin fin... y nunca me muestra los resultados finales.

Comment: @CarlosAgustinGuanipaAlvarez en tal caso te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta centrada en el nuevo problema. Andar editando una pregunta para abarcar varios problemas solo sirve para crear confusión.